# AWS Lambda Function: Error message under API Gateway trigger when using Stage Variables in Lambda Function name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I get the following error when viewing an API Gateway trigger under my Lambda Function:

`The API with ID ... doesn’t include a resource with path ... having an integration ... on the POST method.`

The error is because I am using Stage Variables in the Lambda function name definition within the API. If I replace the Stage Variable for the hardcoded value specific to one environment this error goes away.

Is there anyway to get rid of this error while keeping the use of Stage Variables in the API Gateway?

Comment: Unfortunately not, looks like it just isn't possible at the moment.